# <a> tag inside <li> padding transition moves the list on hovering the first element

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to do a list with a `padding-left` transition on hovering the tag inside the `<li>` tag, as you can see in the following fiddle:

```css
li {
    padding-left: 0;
    transition: padding 0.5s ease-out;
}
li:hover {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
div {
    display: flex;
    padding: 5% 20%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/4/46/Yoda.JPG" alt="Yoda from wikipedia" width=300 height=300>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Send me an email!</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Give me a call!</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

If you hover over (sorry) the first element (*'Send me an email'*), you will see that the image on the left gets pushed away, while this does not happen if you hover over (sorry again) the second element (*'Give me a call'*).

I'd like to achieve the second behaviour for all the elements in the list, but I cannot solve the problem with the first element. What's wrong with the code? Is it a bug?

Code was tested both on Edge and Chrome (latest versions).

Comment: Hmm if I put this into a fiddle I can't reproduce it: http://jsfiddle.net/bb3sy508/ but in your code snippet I can see what you're talking about.

Comment: Check my updated answer.

Comment: @pgruber I don't know why, but if I click on your fiddle I can also see the problem there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the width in `UL` and adjust the padding in div accordingly.

```css
ul{border:1px solid red;width:300px;}/* Specify the width */


li {
    padding-left: 0;
    transition: padding 0.5s ease-out;
}
li:hover {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
div {
    display: flex;
    padding: 5% 10%;  /* Specify the width */
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/4/46/Yoda.JPG" alt="Yoda from wikipedia" width=300 height=300/>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Send me an email!</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Give me a call!</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this help.!

Answer (score 1):

You had `padding-left: 10px` on hover CSS, so on hover the width of the `li` expands by `10px` and if there isn't enough space for the new width, the image moves as the `li` adjusts to accommodate the extra `10px`.

**Solution:** Set a width that is equals the normal width of the `li+10px` for the `ul` and at least a min-width for the `li`. That way it will accommodate the `10ppx` when the padding is added.

```css
ul {
  
  display: block;
   width: 150px; /* Set an accomodating width for the ul */
  }


li {
 
    transition: padding 0.5s ease-out;
  min-width: 150px;
  display: inline-blcok;
 
}
li:hover {
  padding-left: 10px;
    
}

div {
    display: flex;
    padding: 5% 20%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/4/46/Yoda.JPG" alt="Yoda from wikipedia" width=300 height=300>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Send me an email!</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Give me a call!</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**Note:** Study what I did and adjust as needed.

Answer (score 1):

Use css [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform) instead of padding

```css
li a{
    display: block;
    transform: translateX(0);
    transition: transform 0.5s ease-out;
}
li:hover a{
    transform: translateX(10px);
}
div {
    display: flex;
    padding: 5% 20%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/4/46/Yoda.JPG" alt="Yoda from wikipedia" width=300 height=300>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Send me an email!</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Give me a call!</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only reason it's not happening on the second `<li>` is because its width is more than 10px less than the first `<li>`.

If you don't want the image to move you will have to either not center your div or make your `<ul>` bigger so the `<li>`'s can expand without the `<ul>` expanding

Answer (score 0):

Adding padding to the `li` elements makes them wider.

Since the first `li` is already the widest, increasing its width also increases the width of the parent `ul` and grandparent `div` that contains the image. Since the `div` is centered on the screen, widening it has the effect of moving the leftmost content (the `img`) to the left.

Even with the padding, the second `li` is not as wide as the first, so adding the padding to it does not change the width of the grandparent `div`, so the image does not move.

Answer (score 0):

You can try giving the image div a width of 100% and it works well.

```css
li {
    padding-left: 0;
    transition: padding 0.5s ease-out;
}
li:hover {
    padding-left: 10px;
}
div {
    display: flex;
    padding: 5% 20%;
    width: 100%;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/it/4/46/Yoda.JPG" alt="Yoda from wikipedia" width=300 height=300>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Send me an email!</a>

        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Give me a call!</a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```